# What if electric force was independent of the distance?

Tags: electrostatics

The electric force between two charged particles becomes weaker with increasing distance. Suppose instead that the electric force were  independent of distance. In this case, would a charged comb still cause a neutral insulator to become polarized?  Why or why not?  Would the neutral insulator still be attracted to the comb?  Again, why or why not?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics SE.  Feel free to look around, and please take the Tour (under 'help' on the top menu). As it stands, this question is a counter-factual that does not address real physics. It could, perhaps, be reworded to ask about polarization in a static field. But, you would have to show your work and thoughts about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Speculative question... highly speculative "answer".

If force is independent of distance, then a neutral object could still be polarized (positive charges are displaced one way, negative charges displaced the opposite way, in accordance with the force they feel), but since the neutral object contains the same amount of charge after polarization, there could be no net force on the object. Interesting to contemplate that in order to create polarization, work would have to be done on the charges; this work would have to come from a force on the comb and the displacement of comb relative to charge - and it would have to be a net repulsive force.

Not sure how to reconcile these two things. That's the problem with "un" physics... there is no reason for the charges to remain "together" at all since the force doesn't get stronger as they get closer, and matter as we know it would not even exist. Getting contradictions like this is often a good sign that "yeah, that physics can't work".